# How can I find and fix memory leaks in LibGDX?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, libgdx

I'm working on a level editor for my game I'm developing with LibGDX and I'm coming across some memory leak issues. I presume it's because I wasn't properly disposing of my `Texture`s, but after fiddling around with it a little I'm getting Java Runtime errors After some research I'm recognizing them as being because of duplicate `dispose()` calls but I can't seem to determine where the duplicates are happening.

Whenever I draw the game tiles to my screen, it progressively consumes more and more hundreds of megabytes of RAM over time somewhat proportionally to the amount of tiles I have placed. I'm probably just blind or something but I would like this to be fixed relatively soon (the game is for my senior project) and I'm struggling to figure it out, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

EditorScreen.java

```
package com.epicoweo.platformereditor.screens;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputMultiplexer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.Format;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.PixmapIO;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils;
import com.epicoweo.platformereditor.PlatformerEditor;
import com.epicoweo.platformereditor.etc.Drawable;
import com.epicoweo.platformereditor.etc.Refs;
import com.epicoweo.platformereditor.tile.Tile;
import com.epicoweo.platformereditor.tile.Tile.TileTexture;
import com.epicoweo.platformereditor.tile.Tile.TileType;
import com.epicoweo.platformereditor.ui.ButtonFunctions;
import com.epicoweo.platformereditor.ui.MenuTab;
import com.epicoweo.platformereditor.ui.SideBar;
import com.epicoweo.platformereditor.ui.TileChooser;

public class EditorScreen implements Screen {

    public static OrthographicCamera camera;
    Vector3 ogCamera = new Vector3();
    final PlatformerEditor game;
    
    Array<SideBar> editorSideBars;
    TileChooser tc;
    public static int editorWidth = 800;
    public static int editorHeight = 720;
    public static float editorX = (Refs.APP_WIDTH - editorWidth) / 2f;
    public static float editorY = 0;
    
    public static int mapWidth = 25;
    public static int mapHeight = 25;
    
    public static float gridSquareSize = (editorWidth) / (mapWidth+1);
    
    public static Array<Array<Tile>> tileGrid;
    public static Array<Array<Tile>> entityGrid;
    public static Array<Array<Tile>> etcGrid;
    
    public static Array<Array<Tile>> currentGrid;
    
    public static Array<Rectangle> mapSections = new Array<Rectangle>();
    
    public static float currentRotation = 0;
    
    public static Stage stage = new Stage();
    
    public static Array<Texture> allTextures = new Array<Texture>();
    public static Array<Drawable> drawables = new Array<Drawable>();
    
    
    boolean dragging = false;
    boolean creatingTiles = true;
    Array<int[]> draggedTiles;
    
    public EditorScreen(final PlatformerEditor game) {
        this.game = game;
        Refs.game = game;
        
        this.editorSideBars = new Array<SideBar>();
        
        tileGrid = new Array<Array<Tile>>();
        entityGrid = new Array<Array<Tile>>();
        etcGrid = new Array<Array<Tile>>();
        
        draggedTiles = new Array<int[]>();
        
        currentGrid = tileGrid;
        
        //make empty grid
        for(int i = 0; i < mapHeight; i++) {
            tileGrid.add(new Array<Tile>());
            entityGrid.add(new Array<Tile>());
            etcGrid.add(new Array<Tile>());
            for(int j = 0; j < mapWidth; j++) {
                tileGrid.get(i).add(new Tile(0, 0, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, TileTexture.EMPTY));
                entityGrid.get(i).add(new Tile(0, 0, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, TileTexture.EMPTY));
                etcGrid.get(i).add(new Tile(0, 0, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, TileTexture.EMPTY));
            }
        }
        
        setupCamera();
        setupSideBars();
        
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }
    
    void setCurrentGrid() {
        TileTexture tt = tc.selectedTile.tt;
        
        switch(tt.type) {
        case "tile":
            currentGrid = tileGrid;
            break;
        case "etc":
            currentGrid = etcGrid;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        
    }
    
    void setupSideBars() {
        tc = new TileChooser(0, 0, editorX, Refs.APP_HEIGHT-editorY);
        editorSideBars.add(tc);
        editorSideBars.add(new MenuTab(editorX + editorWidth, editorY, Refs.APP_WIDTH-editorX, Refs.APP_HEIGHT-editorY));
    }
    
    void setupCamera() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, Refs.APP_WIDTH, Refs.APP_HEIGHT);
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2f, camera.viewportHeight / 2f, 0);
        camera.update();
        ogCamera = new Vector3(camera.position.x, camera.position.y, 0);
    }
    
    public static void rotate() {
        EditorScreen.currentRotation += 90;
        EditorScreen.currentRotation = Math.floorMod((int)EditorScreen.currentRotation, 360);
    }
    
    public static void saveLevel() throws IOException {
        String folder = createMapFolder();
        saveAsPng(folder);
        saveSections(folder);
    }
    
    public static String createMapFolder() throws IOException {
        String folderName = "../output/map";
        int num = 0;
        while(new File(folderName + num).exists()) {
            num++;
        }
        File newFile = new File(folderName + num);
        newFile.mkdir();
        return folderName + num;
    }
    
    public static void saveAsPng(String folder) { //save the map as a png
        Pixmap mainPix = new Pixmap(mapWidth, mapHeight, Format.RGBA8888);
        for(int i = 0; i < tileGrid.size; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < tileGrid.get(i).size; j++) {
                //red channel: tiles; green: entities; blue: etc
                mainPix.setColor(new Color(tileGrid.get(i).get(j).tt.textureId/255f,
                        entityGrid.get(i).get(j).tt.textureId/255f,
                        etcGrid.get(i).get(j).tt.textureId/255f, 1));
                mainPix.drawPixel(j, i); //x, y
            }
        }
        PixmapIO.writePNG(new FileHandle(folder + "/mainpix.png"), mainPix);    
        mainPix.dispose();
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void saveSections(String folder) throws IOException {
        String savePath = folder + "/mapsections.json";
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(savePath);
        
        JSONArray jsonMapSections = new JSONArray();
        for(Rectangle section : mapSections) {
            JSONObject jsonSection = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray fromCoords = new JSONArray();
            JSONArray toCoords = new JSONArray();
            System.out.println(section);
            fromCoords.add(section.x);
            fromCoords.add(section.y);
            toCoords.add(section.x + section.width);
            toCoords.add(section.y + section.height);
            
            jsonSection.put("fromCoords", fromCoords);
            jsonSection.put("toCoords", toCoords);
            jsonMapSections.add(jsonSection);
        }
        
        fw.write(jsonMapSections.toJSONString());
        fw.close();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void show() {
        
    }

    public void replaceGridSquare(int x, int y) {
        if(!currentGrid.get(y).get(x).isEmpty) {
            currentGrid.get(y).set(x, new Tile(0, 0, 16, 16, TileTexture.EMPTY));
        } else {
            currentGrid.get(y).set(x, tc.selectedTile.duplicate());
            currentGrid.get(y).get(x).rotation = currentRotation;
        }
    }
    
    public void renderMapEditor() {
        
        ShapeRenderer r = new ShapeRenderer();
        
        //make background
        r.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        r.setColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
        r.rect(editorX, editorY, editorWidth, editorHeight);
        r.end();
        //render grid
        r.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        r.begin(ShapeType.Line);
        r.setColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < mapWidth; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < mapHeight; j++) {
                r.rect(editorX + (i)*gridSquareSize, editorY + (j)*gridSquareSize, gridSquareSize, gridSquareSize);
            }
        }
        r.end();
        
        Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
        camera.unproject(mousePosition);
        
        
        //allow user to insert tiles
        if(!ButtonFunctions.mapSectionFlag) {
            for(int i = 0; i < mapWidth; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < mapHeight; j++) {        
                    Vector3 rectVector = new Vector3(editorX +(i)*gridSquareSize, editorY + (j)*gridSquareSize, 0);
                    
                    int[] coords = {i, j};
                    if(new Rectangle(rectVector.x, rectVector.y, gridSquareSize, gridSquareSize)
                            .contains(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y)) {
                        if(Gdx.input.isButtonJustPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)) {
                            dragging = true;
                            draggedTiles.add(coords);
                            creatingTiles = currentGrid.get(j).get(i).isEmpty;
                            
                            replaceGridSquare(i, j);
                        } else if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)) {
                            if(dragging && !draggedTiles.contains(coords, true)) {
                                if(creatingTiles && currentGrid.get(j).get(i).isEmpty) {
                                    replaceGridSquare(i, j);
                                }
                                else if(!creatingTiles && !currentGrid.get(j).get(i).isEmpty) {
                                    replaceGridSquare(i, j);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            dragging = false;
                            draggedTiles.clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        //render squares 
        SpriteBatch b = new SpriteBatch();
        b.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        b.begin();
        for(int i = 0; i < mapHeight; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < mapWidth; j++) {
                drawTilesAt(b, i, j);
            }
        }
        b.end();
        
        //render side bars
        for(SideBar sb : this.editorSideBars) {
            sb.render();
        }
    }
    
    public static void drawScaledRegion(SpriteBatch b, TextureRegion t, int i, int j) {
        b.draw(t, editorX + (j)*gridSquareSize, editorY + (i)*gridSquareSize,
                t.getRegionWidth()/2, t.getRegionHeight()/2,
                t.getRegionWidth(), t.getRegionHeight(),
                1f, 1f, tileGrid.get(i).get(j).rotation);
    }
    
    public static void drawTilesAt(SpriteBatch b, int i, int j) {
        Array<Array<Array<Tile>>> grids = new Array<Array<Array<Tile>>>();
        grids.add(tileGrid, entityGrid, etcGrid);
        int k = 0;
        for(Array<Array<Tile>> grid : grids) {
            if(grid.get(i).get(j).isEmpty) continue;
            Texture texture = Refs.scaleTexture(grid.get(i).get(j).texture,
                    (int)grid.get(i).get(j).width, (int)grid.get(i).get(j).height);
            
            TextureRegion drawTexture = new TextureRegion(texture);
            
            if(k == 0) {
                if(grid.get(i).get(j).type == TileType.PLATFORM) {
                    b.draw(drawTexture, editorX + (j)*gridSquareSize, editorY + (int)((i+0.75f)*gridSquareSize),
                        drawTexture.getRegionWidth()/2, drawTexture.getRegionHeight()/2,
                        drawTexture.getRegionWidth(), drawTexture.getRegionHeight(),
                        1f, 1f, tileGrid.get(i).get(j).rotation);
                } else {
                    drawScaledRegion(b, drawTexture, i, j);
                }
            } else {
                drawScaledRegion(b, drawTexture, i, j);
            }
            allTextures.add(texture);
            k++; 
        }
    }
    
    public static void updateMapSize() {
        
        int oldWidth = tileGrid.get(0).size;
        int oldHeight = tileGrid.size;
        //update grid
        boolean flag = false;
        int oldOldHeight = oldHeight;
        while(oldHeight < mapHeight) {
            tileGrid.add(new Array<Tile>());
            entityGrid.add(new Array<Tile>());
            etcGrid.add(new Array<Tile>());
            
            oldHeight++;
            flag=true;
        }
        if(flag) {
            for(int i = oldOldHeight; i < mapHeight; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < mapWidth; j++) {
                    tileGrid.get(i).add(new Tile(0, 0, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, TileTexture.EMPTY));
                    entityGrid.get(i).add(new Tile(0, 0, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, TileTexture.EMPTY));
                    etcGrid.get(i).add(new Tile(0, 0, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, TileTexture.EMPTY));
                }
            }
        }
        
        while(oldHeight > mapHeight) {
            tileGrid.pop();
            entityGrid.pop();
            etcGrid.pop();
            oldHeight--;
        }
        
        while(oldWidth < mapWidth) {
            for(int i = 0; i < mapHeight; i++) {
                tileGrid.get(i).add(new Tile(0, 0, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, TileTexture.EMPTY));
                entityGrid.get(i).add(new Tile(0, 0, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, TileTexture.EMPTY));
                etcGrid.get(i).add(new Tile(0, 0, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, TileTexture.EMPTY));
            }
            
            oldWidth++;
        }
        while(oldWidth > mapWidth) {
            for(int i = 0; i < mapHeight; i++) {
                tileGrid.get(i).pop();
                entityGrid.get(i).pop();
                etcGrid.get(i).pop();
            }
            oldWidth--;
        }
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        ScreenUtils.clear(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
        camera.update();
        renderMapEditor();
        setCurrentGrid();
        
        getInput();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < Refs.buttons.size; i++) {
            Refs.buttons.get(i).render();
        }
        
        ShapeRenderer r = new ShapeRenderer();
        r.begin(ShapeType.Line);
        r.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        for(Rectangle rect : mapSections) {
            r.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            r.rect(EditorScreen.editorX+rect.x*EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, EditorScreen.editorY+rect.y*EditorScreen.gridSquareSize,
                    rect.width*EditorScreen.gridSquareSize, rect.height*EditorScreen.gridSquareSize);
        }
        r.end();
        r.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        r.dispose();
        
        stage.draw();
        stage.act();
    }
    
    void getInput() {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) {
            camera.translate(-5*camera.zoom, 0, 0);
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) {
            camera.translate(5*camera.zoom, 0, 0);
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)) {
            camera.translate(0, -5*camera.zoom, 0);
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) {
            camera.translate(0, 5*camera.zoom, 0);
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) {
            camera.zoom += 0.02;
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.Q)) {
            camera.zoom -= 0.02;
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.Z)) {
            camera.zoom = 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        
        if(width > 0f && height > 0f) {
            
            float scale = (float)editorWidth/(float)Refs.APP_WIDTH;
            editorWidth = (int)(width*scale);
            editorHeight = height;
            
            Refs.APP_WIDTH = width;
            Refs.APP_HEIGHT = height;
            
            editorX = (Refs.APP_WIDTH - editorWidth) / 2f;
            editorY = 0;
            gridSquareSize = (int)((float)editorWidth) / ((float)mapWidth + 1);
        
            for(SideBar sb : this.editorSideBars) {
                //sb.resize(width, height);
            }
        }
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(Texture t : allTextures) {
            t.dispose();
        }
        
        for(Drawable d : drawables) {
            d.texture.dispose();
        }
        
        TileTexture.disposeAll();
        
    }

}
```

Tile.java

```
package com.epicoweo.platformereditor.tile;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.Filter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.Format;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException;
import com.epicoweo.platformereditor.etc.Drawable;
import com.epicoweo.platformereditor.screens.EditorScreen;

public class Tile extends Drawable {

    public String texturePath;
    public boolean isEmpty = false;
    public float rotation = 0;
    public TileTexture tt;
    public TileType type;
    public float width = EditorScreen.gridSquareSize;
    public float height = EditorScreen.gridSquareSize;
    
    public enum TileTexture {
        //maplayout
        EMPTY("", 0, "tile"), STONE("./textures/tiles/stone.png", 1, "tile"), GRASS("./textures/tiles/grass.png", 2, "tile"),
        DIRT("./textures/tiles/dirt.png", 3, "tile"), GRAVITYSWAP("./textures/tiles/gravityswap.png", 4, "tile"),
        SPEEDBOOST("./textures/tiles/speedboost_0.png", 5, "tile"), PLATFORM0("./textures/tiles/platform_0.png", 6, "tile"), 
        PLATFORM1("./textures/tiles/platform_1.png", 7, "tile"), PLATFORM2("./textures/tiles/platform_2.png", 8, "tile"),
        
        //mapetc
        PLAYER("./textures/player/player_left.png", 1, "etc");
        
        String texturePath;
        public Texture texture;
        public int textureId;
        public String type;
        
        TileTexture(String texturePath, int textureId, String type) {
            this.texturePath = texturePath;
            this.textureId = textureId;
            this.type = type;
            try {
                texture = new Texture(this.texturePath);
            } catch(GdxRuntimeException e) {
                texture = new Texture(new Pixmap(16, 16, Format.Alpha));
            }
        }
        
        public static void disposeAll() {
            for(TileTexture t : TileTexture.values()) {
                t.texture.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public enum TileType {
        
        FULL("full"), SLOPE_45("slope45"), PLATFORM("platform");
        
        String s;
        TileType(String s) {
            this.s = s;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return s;
        }
    }
    
    public Tile(float x, float y, float width, float height, TileTexture texture, TileType type) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
        
        texturePath = texture.texturePath;
        
        this.type = type;
        this.tt = texture;
        
        
        if(type == TileType.SLOPE_45) {
            //remove png and add _45.png
            texturePath = texture.texturePath.substring(0, texture.texturePath.length() - 4) + "_45.png";
        }
        if(texture != TileTexture.EMPTY) {
            if(type != TileType.PLATFORM) {
                Pixmap pixmap16 = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal(texturePath));
                Pixmap pixmap64 = new Pixmap(64, 64, pixmap16.getFormat());
                
                pixmap64.setFilter(Filter.NearestNeighbour);
                pixmap64.drawPixmap(pixmap16,
                        0, 0, pixmap16.getWidth(), pixmap16.getHeight(),
                        0, 0, pixmap64.getWidth(), pixmap64.getHeight()
                );
                
                Texture t64 = new Texture(pixmap64);
                
                if(this.texture != null) {
                    this.texture.dispose();
                }
                this.texture = t64;
                
                pixmap16.dispose();
                pixmap64.dispose();
            } else {
                this.height = EditorScreen.gridSquareSize / 4;
                
                Pixmap pixmap16 = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal(texturePath));
                Pixmap pixmap64 = new Pixmap(64, 16, pixmap16.getFormat());
                
                pixmap64.setFilter(Filter.NearestNeighbour);
                pixmap64.drawPixmap(pixmap16,
                        0, 0, pixmap16.getWidth(), pixmap16.getHeight(),
                        0, 0, pixmap64.getWidth(), pixmap64.getHeight()
                );
                
                Texture t64 = new Texture(pixmap64);
                
                if(this.texture != null) {
                    this.texture.dispose();
                }
                this.texture = t64;
                
                
                pixmap16.dispose();
                pixmap64.dispose();
            }
        } else {
            this.texture = texture.texture;
            isEmpty = true;
        }
        
    }
    
    public Tile(float x, float y, float width, float height, TileTexture texture) {
        this(x, y, width, height, texture, TileType.FULL);
        
    }
    public Tile(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        this(x, y, width, height, TileTexture.STONE, TileType.FULL);
        
    }
    
    public Tile duplicate() {
        Tile newTile = new Tile(x, y, width, height, tt, type);
        return newTile;
    }
    
    
}
```

If any extra info is needed please let me know!

Comment: Use [AssetManager](https://libgdx.com/wiki/managing-your-assets) to handle all this. It is very powerful and pretty much a must-use feature. When you use AssetManager, you call `assetManager.unload()` instead of `dispose()` and it safely  disposes it as long as it isn't currently used by a loaded dependent asset. For example, if you unload a Texture that is also part of a TextureAtlas, then it doesn't dispose it yet.